# Google App Engine - low-level datastore API flag?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

In my GAE-Java app, I'm using the low-level datastore API. Hence I don't need the GAE app instance to load any of the higher level data access libraries such as JPA, JDO, Data Nucleus, etc.

Is there a flag that I can set to indicate that I don't want these libraries to be loaded?

My motivation to do this is to reduce app instance startup time everywhere I can. Now I don't know if these libraries are loaded only on-demand or always. The dev environment logs messages related to data nucleus which seems to indicate that some of these libraries may be pre-loaded? I hope I'm wrong here.

Thanks,
Keyur

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to tell App Engine not to load these libraries, just don't include their JARs in your project.

Comment: Thanks, Jason. I was under the impression that uploading an app didn't upload the GAE JARs along with the app but were referenced from a common location. But if that is not the case, then I get to exercise my fav hobby - deleting files :-)